# uwp how to resize items in a templated item source all at once?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have this listview and I want to dynamically resize the item's properties (fontsize, width and height etc..) upon a window's size change. So far I've been able to do so by modifying item source's elements' layout one by one in c# (with a for loop). As the listview items' count grows, the effect becomes glitchy later on. I wonder if there is a way to uniformly modify the style of these templated items in listview. I've tried using and modifying a staticResource style that is applied to the template but to no avail.

```
 <ListView
        x:Name="leftMenubar"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Height="auto"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="LeftBarMenuItemClicked"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Items}"
        Loaded="LeftMenubar_Loaded">
        <ListView.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundPointerOver" Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundPressed" Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPressed" Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelected" Color="Transparent" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListViewItemBackgroundSelectedPointerOver" Color="Transparent" />
        </ListView.Resources>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <ItemsStackPanel
                    Margin="0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    GroupPadding="0"
                    Orientation="Vertical" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:LeftMenuBarItem">
                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="{x:Bind Pad, Mode=OneWay}">
                    <BitmapIcon
                        Height="{x:Bind IconHeight, Mode=OneWay}"
                        MinHeight="20"
                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        Foreground="{x:Bind Foreground, Mode=OneWay}"
                        UriSource="{x:Bind ImgPath}" />
                    <TextBlock
                        Width="Auto"
                        Margin="0,5,0,0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        FontSize="10"
                        Foreground="{x:Bind Foreground, Mode=OneWay}"
                        Text="{x:Bind Title}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this a few different ways. You could setup the data template to bind the font size to the height of the control and calculate there. But then you have a converter firing for every item in your list.

I think the best way is to setup one binding for the `ListViewItem` to the `FontSize` (and other properties) on the `ListView` Here is an example of how you can set this up

```
class AdjustableListView : ListView
{
    public AdjustableListView()
    {
        SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
    }

    protected override void PrepareContainerForItemOverride(DependencyObject element, object item)
    {
        base.PrepareContainerForItemOverride(element, item);

        var listItem = (ListViewItem)element;
        var binding = new Binding { Source = this, Path = new PropertyPath("FontSize")};
        listItem.SetBinding(ListViewItem.FontSizeProperty, binding);
    }

    private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FontSize = Math.Max(12, e.NewSize.Height / 24);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User Controls allow you to encapsulate common passages of XAML that you intend to use frequently, whether on a single page or across the entire app. However, User Controls are most helpful when you want to change the size of the data template for a GridView or ListView when employing an adaptive layout, I think that this is the best approach to do the task.

This video shows you how.

[Bob Tabor explaining how to utilize User Controls as Data Templates](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ksliZGMMj8k)